# How to reopen rejected review

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I have approved an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10838768) which has been rejected by another three reviewers. Anyway I think I was correct at least a bit. The edit consists of a comment and code change. I suppose that the code change is correct and the comment could be rejected.

I suppose that this edit should be somehow reopened and the code change approved. What should I do now? Should I just edit the the answer?

Comment: If S L Barth rejects, I'd go blindly with rejection. I'd have rejected on my own. The user is still active, just comment on the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should've been a comment.

If the answer's code is incorrect, correct it in a comment, explaining what went wrong. Don't just edit it.

That said, there is no way to "Re-submit" a rejected edit, other than suggesting the edit again.